# What is the equivalent of <x,y,z> in spherical coordinates?

Tags: vectors, spherical-coordinates

I know this is a very newbie question, but what is the equivalent of

$\langle x,y,z \rangle$

in spherical coordinates? I'd think it would be

$\langle r, \theta, \phi \rangle$

but the divergences are very different. Is my vector incorrect, or is my calculation of divergence wrong?

As recommended by a comment, here are calculations for divergences:

$$\nabla \cdot \vec r = {\partial \over\partial x}x + {\partial \over\partial y}y + {\partial \over\partial z}z = 3$$
$$\nabla \cdot \vec r = {1\over r^2}{\partial\over\partial r}(r^2 r) + {1\over r\sin\theta}{\partial\over\partial\theta}(\theta\sin\theta) + {1\over r\sin\theta}{\partial \over\partial \phi}\phi = 3 + {\sin\theta + \theta\cos\theta\over r\sin\theta} + {\phi\over r\sin\theta} \neq 3 ??$$

Comment: What divergences ? You need to show your calculations here --

Comment: Question edited to show divergence calculations

Comment: $(x, y, z) = (r \cos \theta \cos \varphi, r\sin \theta \cos \varphi, r\sin \varphi)$

Comment: @PaulSinclair That doesn't seem quite right to me, shouldn't the radial component be the length of the vector be $r$? Can you please explain how this works? As you can tell I'm a bit confused. Thanks.

Comment: For the divergences to be the same you would have to take the divergence of the same vector. So you would need to ensure that your $r$, $\theta$ and $\phi$ values matched the $x$, $y$ and $z$ values at all points

Comment: In particular, consider how the unit vectors in one system are related to those in another

Comment: @TylerHG Thanks, my understanding is that for a point $(x,y,z)$, we can specify $\theta$ and $\phi$ to point the right direction and go $r$ in the direction specified by $\theta$ and $\phi$. Is this correct?

Comment: Look at the part on unit vectors https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Comment: @TylerHG Thanks for the pointer. That page tells me that $(x,y,z) = (r,0,0)$. I had considered this, but it doesn't make much sense to me (see discussion of answer below).

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to understand. To describe a position in spherical coordinates one must use $r$, $\theta$ and $\phi$. But for a vector field at some position, $\hat r$ is not constant and $\hat\theta$ and $\hat\phi$ become "adjustments". So for a field $\vec F = \langle r, 0, 0\rangle$, $\vec F(r, \theta,\phi) \neq \langle r,\theta,\phi\rangle$ unlike the field $\vec F = \langle x,y,z\rangle$ where $\vec F(x,y,z) = \langle x,y,z\rangle$. That sounded kind of obvious but it was quite confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\theta$ and $\phi$ components of the position vector $\vec r$ are $0$.  That is to write that

$$\hat \theta \cdot \vec r=\hat \phi \cdot \vec r=0$$

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot \vec r&=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial r^2(\hat r\cdot \vec r)}{\partial r}\\\\
&+\frac{1}{r\sin \theta}\frac{\partial \sin \theta (\hat \theta \cdot \vec r)}{\partial}\\\\
&+\frac{1}{r\sin \theta}\frac{\partial (\hat \phi \cdot \vec r)}{\partial \phi}\\\\
&=3+0+0\\\\
&=3
\end{align}$$

as expected

Comment: So you're suggesting that $\langle x,y,z\rangle = \langle r, 0, 0\rangle$? I had considered this as well, but it didn't make much intuitive geometrical sense to me - with $\theta = 0$, doesn't the vector always point in the +z direction?

Comment: The position vector points in the direction $$\hat rr=(\hat x\sin \theta \cos \phi+\hat y\sin \theta \sin \phi+\hat z\cos \theta)r$$So, yes.  When $\theta =0$, $\vec r=\hat zr$ and $r=z$, so $\vec r=\hat zz$ as expected!  Albert, what do you think the polar and azimuthal components are for the position vector?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still slightly confused. For example, take the vector field $\vec F = \langle x, y, z\rangle$. Then at $(1,0,0)$, the field points in the $+x$ direction. However for $\vec F = \langle r, 0,0\rangle$, the field at $(1, \pi/2, 0)$ points up?

Comment: Nevermind, the field at $(1,\pi/2, 0)$ points along the x-axis since $\hat r$ points in the $+x$ direction. I think I get it now, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! My pleasure.  And pleased to hear that you have it now.  Well done!!